# Recibir un archivo en JS por http

Tags: javascript, http, filesystem

Uso una función estandarizada para acceder servicios.

Me funciona muy bien pero no sé qué hacer cuando recibo un archivo.

Normalmente, llamo al callback usando el valor json devuelto por el servicio.

En el caso de un archivo, recibo el texto que teóricamente debería escribir como contenido del archivo en el cliente.

Puedo implementar cómo hacer eso, pero pienso que debe haber una forma de menor (Y mejor) nivel para manejar la "bajada" del archivo.

El caso que estoy manejando recibe el archivo de un *res.download* de un servidor Node JS.

Esta es mi función:

```
function accede(accion,url,fn,datos) {
    let xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let xmlEstado = ["No inicializado", "Conectado", "Recibido", "Procesando", "Listo"]

    function msjErrorXML(e) {
        alert(xobj.accion+"\n"+xobj.url+"\n¡E R R O R!!!\nStatus: " +xobj.status +" (" +xobj.statusText+")\n"+xobj.status);
    }

    xobj.accion = accion;
    xobj.url    = url;

    xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    xobj.withCredentials = true;
    xobj.open(accion, url, true);
    xobj.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/json; charset=utf-8');
    xobj.onerror = msjErrorXML;
    xobj.onreadystatechange = () => { console.log(xobj.readyState, url, xmlEstado[xobj.readyState]," (", xobj.status,")") };
    xobj.onload = () => {
        if (xobj.status < 400) {
            if(accion === "GET") {
                fn(JSON.parse(xobj.responseText));
            } else {
                fn(JSON.parse(xobj.responseText));
            }
        } else {
            msjErrorXML();
        }
    };
    xobj.send(JSON.stringify(datos));
}
```